# Switch doesn't in full view in match_parrent

Tags: android

I have the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But looks as following

[image]

Here I want the switch to in full view. I don't know what I am missing. Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: did you tried running your code?

Comment: also try setting `android:switchMinWidth="yourwitdth"`

Comment: I'm not sure but the reason may be that android uses a drawable resource that don't stretch in width.